# Bootstrap: `well` inside a `span`/`row` goes beyond its container: how to make it fill "only" width=100% of it?

Tags: css, layout, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with a Bootstrap `well` going beyond its containing element (here a `class="row"` , itself in a `class="span4"`).

It is clearly visible in the JSFidle I did here: http://jsfiddle.net/sebastien_worms/fc42w/2/
And fullscreen : http://jsfiddle.net/sebastien_worms/fc42w/2/embedded/result/

Extract of the code is here:

```
<div class="span4 pull-right">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="well" style="width:100%;">
            <b>This is the well that bothers me !</b><br> It goes beyond the right end of the screen ... And if you click "inspect element", you can see it goes beyond the right-end of its containing "span4" and "row"...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see the well going beyond its containing element (and the screen) when playing with you browser's window size (around 1000px wide is the most visible).

... And obviously, I can't set the `well` in the same `div` as the `span`: http://jsfiddle.net/sebastien_worms/fc42w/3/

How should I do to have the `well` fill 100% (only) of the `span4` ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's beacuse your padding, just add this

```
.well {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

- It will work in any modern browser and IE8 and newer